# Change ASP.NET MVC validation dynamically in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-validation

On one of the view model fields, I have set the min length in ASP.NET MVC Data Annotation attribute.

```
[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "A minimum of 5 digits is required")]
```

Based on a dropdown selection(which has 2 values), MinLength needs to be updated to 10. ClientSideValidation is enable and so validation needs to reflect the changes before it is posted back to the controller.

Tried changing the attribute  "data-val-minlength-min" using jQuery based on dropdown value, but it did not change the validation.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: The html5 data attribute for validation is ONLY for client-side validation. The `MinLength` attribute is used for server-side validation (and to generate the html5 data atribute).

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ, How do I update it to some other value on a drop down change.

Comment: Try by creating a custom attribute by inheriting `MinLength` where the passed value is a default value and when your custom attribute is called by server-side validation, you look in the http request to get the value returned by the dropdown. I don't know if it works, but it's a thing i would try if i had this need.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ, I am having issues with that because the dropdown change does not do any server action. Also the main reason, is the submit button does not allow me to submit to the server as there is client side validation enabled.

Comment: I kind of got a solution. I kept the annotaion for MinLength the same.
[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "A minimum of 5 digits is required")]

In jQuery on dropdown change, validation property is updated to the required value by accessing the property : $('#formName).validate().settings.rules["Comment"].minlength. Also updated the validation message by accessing the property : $('#formName').validate().settings.messages["Comment"].minlength

Comment: The above solution works for me. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. If there is a better one, I will be more than happy to change my code. If there is none, I will post this as answer in a day or two.

Comment: Create you own conditional validation attribute so that you get both client and server side validation - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Looks like I was looking for this. This looks pretty good even though there is a lot of code to be written to achieve something simple. Once I have it up and running, will update this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StephenMuecke gave me the solution I needed. It works on client side and server side as desired. I am posting it as answer so that the next person can easily see it.

Create you own conditional validation attribute so that you get both client and server side validation - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. This is to use RemoteValidations for more than one fields in the model.

```
[Remote("CheckForSelectedDropDownLengthMethod","ControllerName",AdditionalFields="SelectedDropDownName",ErrorMessage="The length should be be 10 characters.")]

public class ControllerName: Controller
{
    public JsonResult CheckForSelectedDropDownLengthMethod(Model yourmodel)
        {
              // write your logic to validate the logic here ,
              // Get the selected value of the dropdown, and the field where you want to check the length.
        }
}
```

**Please follow one of the example** 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/669824/Implementing-Remote-Validation-in-MVC

Comment: This one as the name suggests does the validation remotely so it takes time. I have other validations also in my form and since ClientValidation is enabled, all the other inputs get validated soon. It looks a little odd when only one of them takes some time. I have upvoted a comment from @StephenMuecke. That looks like something I need. I am already half way through that implementation.